# Unable to scan QR Code using Pod - "QRCodeReader.swift" for version 8.2.0

Tags: scanning

In my project I m using Pod - **"QRCodeReader.swift"**, *version 8.2.0.*
Code Repo: https://github.com/yannickl/QRCodeReader.swift

The above mentioned version of the pod has an issue that sometimes it fails to scan the QR Code. The next time I run the app, it starts responding properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use default camera for capturing QR Code. Use AVCaptureSession.

Comment: This is not a question, but a bug report. Better file it at https://github.com/yannickl/QRCodeReader.swift/issues

Comment: I have already reported it. I have put it here so that I can know if there are any work arounds to it.